# Copiar en Linux simultáneamente sin necesidad de script varios archivos a otro directorio renombrándolos

Tags: linux

Estoy intentando, sin necesidad de realizar un script, copiar todos los archivos que tengo en un directorio /$HOME/ParaCopiar a otro directorio /$HOME/CopiaSeg modificándoles el nombre al añadir el texto backup al final.

El comando que intento ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
find ./ParaCopiar -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} CopiaSeg/`basename {}`.backup \;
```

Y el sistema devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error que me hace pensar que no se está ejecutando bien el comando `basename`, ya que no se queda con el nombre del fichero eliminado la ruta, aunque realmente sí se parece que se ejecuta porque no muestra el mensaje de error en ese sentido.

```
ad@ad-virtualbox:~$ find ./ParaCopiar -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} CopiaSeg/`basename {}`.backup \;
cp: no se puede crear el fichero regular 'CopiaSeg/./ParaCopiar/p2.txt.backup': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede crear el fichero regular 'CopiaSeg/./ParaCopiar/p3.odt.backup': No existe el archivo o el directorio
cp: no se puede crear el fichero regular 'CopiaSeg/./ParaCopiar/p1.txt.backup': No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo, o me sugiere otra forma de hacerlo siempre que sea desde línea de comandos sin ejecutar scripts.

Comment: De entrada, el comodín `{}` solo se puede usar una vez. Del man de `find`: "Only one instance of `{}' is allowed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecutando esta línea vas a poder realizar lo que necesitas:

```
find dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs --null -t -I % bash -c 'cp "%" dir2/"$(basename "%")".backup'
```

El comando `find` buscará según el criterio indicado. El comando `xargs` se encarga de pasar el dato como argumento al comando `cp`. Con `-print0` y `--null` garantizas el tratamiento correcto de los espacios en blanco y de los caracteres `\n`. El modificador `-t` (verbose) te muestra cómo queda el comando que se ejecuta (podes omitirlo para mejor rendimiento y no llenar la pantalla de información).

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de ayuda. Disculpa el despiste de no haber consultado la ayuda del man de find con respecto al número de veces que se puede utilizar el comodín {}